# How to use hasktags package for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ctags

According to documentation at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasktags one should first install 
**hasktags** package which I did as

`cabal install hasktags`

then documentation says to generate tags in ctags format do this

`hasktags --ctags .`

but I am getting error from shell as

```
zsh: command not found: hasktags
```

Am I missing something here or is there any other way to use them?

By the way I am trying to use them with VIM.

Comment: Is `~/.cabal/bin` in your PATH variable?

Comment: no! it is not in my PATH variable.

Comment: @Saurabhkukade In that case, you may need to add that directory to your PATH in order to use any executable installed via `cabal`.

Comment: yes added and its working now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ~/.cabal/bin in PATH variable.